# Group by and Count Function returns NaNs

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe (df) that looks like this:

```
visitor  label  response  products  number  pct
abc123   color  blue      3         1       0.333
def456   size   4 x 4     5         5       1.0
def456   shape  round     5         5       1.0
```

I created a new dataframe that only has records where pct = 1.0 with this code:

```
df2 = df
df2["pct"] = 1.0
```

And then I'd like to count the number of records by visitor with a new column called num_same. I tried this:

```
df2["num_same"] = df2.groupby("visit_id").aggregate('count')
```

But my results are all NaN.

I've also tried:

```
df2["num_same"] = df2.groupby("visit_id").size()
```

How can I get the results I want without the NaNs?

Comment: You need `df2["num_same"] = df2.groupby("visit_id")['visit_id'].transform('size')`

Comment: use `df2 = df.copy()` for copying dataframes.